# How can I use VBA to change the "Show" checkbox in a query?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form, Qsearch, that includes code that creates a query based on multi-value selections in the three multi-value list boxes, when a command button is selected.  The query created does not have the Show checkbox checked.  How can I create VBA code that will set the Show checkbox to True?

The VBA code used to build the query is:

```
    strFinalFilter = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " & strFinalFilter
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "search_results"
    Set qdfNew = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("search_results", strFinalFilter)
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is hard to understand: what CheckBox are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to see the show checkbox in query design view or you have show button on your form and you want to store as a true or false in query.

Comment: what do you mean? Is this even an answer?